# Background image repeated downwards

Tags: html, css, html-lists, background-image

I'm unable to figure it out that why my last `background image` is repeated downwards. I have checked HTML thoroughly, and there is no repetition of lists.

Here is my HTML for this css:

```css
 .contact-info a {
   display: block;
   min-height: 20px;
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 20px 20px;
   margin: 0 0 10px;
   padding: 0 0 0 30px;
 }
 .contact-info li.phone a {
   background-image: url('phone.png')
 }
 .contact-info li.mail a {
   background-image: url('mail.png')
 }
 .contact-info li.twitter a {
   background-image: url('../twitter.png')
 }
```

```html
<section>
  <h3>Contact Details</h3>
  <ul class="contact-info">
    <li class="phone">
      <a href="tel:555-555-555">555-555-555</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mail">
      <a href="mailto:keytocheema@gmail.com">Keytocheema@gmail.com
    </li>
    <li class="twitter">
        <a href="#">My twitter</a>
    </li>
</section>
```

Comment: Note that your HTML is ill-formed.  The `<a href="mailto:` element is missing the `</a>`, and you have no `</ul>`.  Results will vary from browser to browser with ill-formed HTML.

Answer (score 1):

You are not closing the `a` tag in the second `li`, also you are missing the closing tag `ul`.

A good way to avoid this kind of mystakes is using an editor with color code.

```css
.contact-info a {
  display: block;
  min-height: 20px;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  margin: 0 0 10px;
  padding: 0 0 0 30px;
}
.contact-info li.phone a {
  background-image: url('//dummyimage.com/20x20&text=1')
}
.contact-info li.mail a {
  background-image: url('//dummyimage.com/20x20&text=2')
}
.contact-info li.twitter a {
  background-image: url('//dummyimage.com/20x20&text=3')
}
```

```html
<ul class="contact-info">
  <li class="phone">
    <a href="tel:555-555-555">555-555-555</a>
  </li>
  <li class="mail">
    <a href="mailto:keytocheema@gmail.com">Keytocheema@gmail.com</a> 
  </li>
  <li class="twitter">
    <a href="#">My twitter</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You haven't closed `<ul>` and `<a>`.

```
<section>
  <h3>Contact Details</h3>
  <ul class="contact-info">
    <li class="phone">
      <a href="tel:555-555-555">555-555-555</a>
    </li>
    <li class="mail">
      <a href="mailto:keytocheema@gmail.com">Keytocheema@gmail.com</a>
    </li>
    <li class="twitter">
        <a href="#">My twitter</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: exactly my answer, why repeat it after 2 hours?

Comment: Sorry, i didn't noticed your answer :/